# How to translate "what" when used as an ironic interjection

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, interrogative, interjection

Is there any good way to translate "what" when used as an ironic interjection, e.g. "What? He thought that would be a good idea?" said in a sarcastic tone? My first thought is just to use quis or quid but I don't know if that translates perfectly or if there's a better alternative.

First time posting here so apologies if I mess anything up. Also, sorry, I don't know if interjection is the correct term, but I don't know my grammatical terms very well and it seemed the closest to how "what" is used in this context. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Latin allows the use of "Quid?" in a similar way.

See, for instance, Cicero in the First Cataline Oration:

> Quid? cum te Praeneste Kalendis ipsis Novembribus occupaturum nocturno impetu esse confideres, sensistine illam coloniam meo iussu meis praesidiis, custodiis, vigiliis esse munitam?

Translation by Yonge:

> What? when you made sure that you would be able to seize Praeneste on the first of November by a nocturnal attack, did you not find that that colony was fortified by my order, by my garrison, by my watchfulness and care?

Also, Plautus, *Menaechmi*, V.5:

> Med. Dic mihi hoc: solent tibi umquam óculi duri fieri?
>   Men. Quid? tu me lucustam censes esse, homo ignavissime?

My translation:

> Med: Tell me this: do your eyes ever get hard?
>   Men. What? Do you think I'm a locust, you good-for-nothing man?